# Упрощение алгоритма для диагонального поиска

Tags: python, алгоритм

Задача простая донельзя, но я что-то застрял. 
Имеется поле H на W
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно пройтись по координатам по диагонали, как показано на картинке.

Вот мой код, но мне кажется задачу можно решить элегантнее, без лишних переменных.

```
H = 11
W = 14

for j in range(0,H+1):
    i = 0
    for k in range(j,-1,-1):
        print(i,k)
        i+=1

for j in range(W,-1,-1):
    i = 0
    for k in range(j,W+1):
        print(i,k)
        i+=1

for j in range(0,H+1):
    i = 0
    for k in range(j,-1,-1):
        print(i,k)
        i+=1

for j in range(W,-1,-1):
    i = H
    for k in range(j,W+1):
        if i<0:
            break
        print(i,k)
        i-=1
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Двумерный массив `table` создаю для демонстрации результата.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pprint import pprint

h = 11
w = 14
table = [[0 for j in range(w + 1)] for i in range(h + 1)]

x, y = 0, 0
step_num = 18
num = 1

while num <= step_num:
    x_tmp = x
    while x_tmp >= 0 and num <= step_num:
        table[y][x_tmp] = num
        x_tmp, y = x_tmp - 1, y + 1
        num += 1

    x, y = x + 1, 0

pprint(table)
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 8, 12, 17, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [6, 9, 13, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [10, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: нужно для всех углов, и до самого конца матрицы

Comment: @yoloy То есть нужно от левого верхнего угла пройти по диагонали до правого нижнего? И так для каждого угла? А зачем число 18 выделено? И чёрный квадрат для чего? Мне показалось, он обозначает границу до которой нужно искать. В любом случае, вы просили подсказку как это сделать и получили её. Дальше пытайтесь сами. Если опять забуксуете, создавайте новый вопрос с новым своим кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот, что вам нужно:

```
H = 11
W = 14

for k in range(0, H+W+1):
    for i in range(0, min(k+1, H+1)):
        y = i
        x = k - i
        if x > W:
            continue
        print(y, x)
```

Comment: Вроде нужно остановиться на числе 18. Я подозреваю, что задача заключается в заполнении всех 4 углов подобным образом.

Comment: нужно для всех углов, и до самого конца матрицы

Answer (score 0):

Объединил два предыдущих ответа в один и дописал поиск для остальных углов:

```
H = 11
W = 14
from pprint import pprint

table = [[0 for j in range(W + 1)] for i in range(H + 1)]
c = 1
for k in range(0, H+W+1):
    for i in range(0, min(k+1, H+1)):
        y = i
        x = k - i
        if x > W:
            continue
        table[y][x] = c
        c+=1

pprint(table)
print()

table = [[0 for j in range(W + 1)] for i in range(H + 1)]
c = 1
for k in range(H+W+1,-1,-1 ):
    for i in range(0, min(k+1, H+1)):
        y = H-i
        x = k - i
        if x > W:
            continue
        table[y][x] = c
        c+=1

pprint(table)
print()

table = [[0 for j in range(W + 1)] for i in range(H + 1)]
c = 1
for k in range(0, H+W+1):
    for i in range(0, min(k+1, H+1)):
        y = H-i
        x = k - i
        if x > W:
            continue
        table[y][x] = c
        c+=1

pprint(table)

table = [[0 for j in range(W + 1)] for i in range(H + 1)]
c = 1
for k in range(H+W+1,-1,-1 ):
    for i in range(0, min(k+1, H+1)):
        y = i
        x = k - i
        if x > W:
            continue
        table[y][x] = c
        c+=1

pprint(table)
print()
```